# Условий, оптимизация кода

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть операция по изменению категории,
значении категории -   `1,2,3,4`
Мне нужно оптимизировать кусок кода где идет проверка
`cat_old` - значение старой категории
`cat_new` - значение новой категории
Категорию  можно менять не  более **одной категории выше или ниже**
*Нельзя менять категорию  к примеру с 3 на 1 или 1 на 4*
Как оптимизировать данный кусок кода:
Мой код:

```
if     (cat_old=1 and cat_new  = 2) or (cat_old=2 and cat_new  = 3) or (cat_old=3 and cat_new  = 4)
    or (cat_old=4 and cat_new  = 3) or (cat_old=2 and cat_new  = 1) or (cat_old=3 and cat_new  = 2)
then                                              
     ----выполнение ряд операции 
     if cat_old in(3,2) and cat_new in(2,1) and sum1<=sum2
       ---вызов операции
     else if sum1>sum2 and cat_old in(3,2) and cat_new in(2,1) then
     -- ошибка изменение невозможно
     else    
       ---вызов операции
end if;
else      
     -----Error нельзя менять на указанную   категории
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Категорию можно менять не более одной категории выше или ниже

Ну так и напишите в коде - "разница должна быть равна единице":

```
if abs(cat_old - cat_new) = 1 then
```

Далее, у вас идет

```
if cat_old in(3,2) and cat_new in(2,1) and sum1<=sum2
   ---вызов операции
 else if sum1>sum2 and cat_old in(3,2) and cat_new in(2,1) then
   -- ошибка изменение невозможно
 else    
   ---вызов операции
end if;
```

Ошибка появляется только в одном случае, проверяйте его (при условии, что операция одна и та же):

```
if sum1>sum2 and cat_old in(3,2) and cat_new in(2,1) then
 -- ошибка изменение невозможно
 else    
   ---вызов операции
end if;
```